# Displaying in openGL based on a matrix

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to draw some shapes in the openGL window. I draw these shapes based on the values in a particular matrix. I am using glut which has a function glutDisplayFunc that takes 1 parameter, a function callback taking no arguments and returns void. But I need to draw an image on the window based on a matrix which I cannot pass to the function callback.

This is an example code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#define pi 3.142857
void mat()
{
        int a[2][2];
    //
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
}
// function to initialize
void myInit (void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-780, 780, -420, 420);
}

void display (void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    float x, y, i;
    for ( i = 0; i < (2 * pi); i += 0.001)
    {
        x = 200 * cos(i);
        y = 200 * sin(i);

        glVertex2i(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    // giving window size in X- and Y- direction
    glutInitWindowSize(1366, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Circle Drawing");
    myInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I need to be able to use the matrix a in function mat to define the center of 2 circles. How do I draw the window from within the mat function?
Edit:included code and fixed some typos

Comment: Welcome to SO - please post your code

Comment: It's more the question of c for how to pass variable into function which doesn't accept any parameter. In this case for glut, I didn't see other cleaner possibility rather than define your input matrix as global variable as `static int a[2][2]` (I stick to `int` type as per your code, but I believe you mean `float` and it might be 3x3 or 4x4 matrix for `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix). Before rendering you can normally accept input for your `a` matrix, then inside `display()` you just refer variable `a` normally.

Answer (score 1):

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //-----------
    float a[4][4] = {
        1,0,0,0,
        0,1,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,1 };

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glLoadMatrixf((float*)a);
    //----------

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    float x, y, i;
    for (i = 0; i < (2 * pi); i += 0.001)
    {
        x = 200 * cos(i);
        y = 200 * sin(i);

        glVertex2i(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you can load the current model view matrix, by setting the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix mode ([`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)), and loading the matrix by [`glLoadMatrixf`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml).
Optionally the matrix can be multiplied to the current matrix by [`glMultMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml).

But in both cases, the matrix has to be 4x4 [Transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). The parameter to both functions is a pointer to an array of 16 `float`s respectively an 2 dimensional 4x4 `float`-array.
Init a 4x4 [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) and read the upper left 2x2, to set up a rotation matrix around the z-axis:

Further, I recommend to read an rotation angle in degree and to calculate the rotation axis by the trigonometric functions `sin` respectively `cos`. 
Finally read the xy translation components:

```c
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
```

```c
float a[4][4];

void mat()
{
    // init identity matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            a[i][j] = (i==j) ? 1.0f : 0.0f; 

    // read the angle in degrees
    float angle_degree;
    scanf("%f", &angle_degree);

    // convert the angle to radian
    float angle_radiant = angle_degree * (float)M_PI / 180.0f;

    // set rotation around z-axis
    float cos_ang = cos(angle_radiant); 
    float sin_ang = sin(angle_radiant); 
    a[0][0] = cos_ang; 
    a[0][1] = -sin_ang;
    a[1][0] = sin_ang;
    a[1][1] = cos_ang;  

    // read translation
    scanf("%f", &a[3][0]);
    scanf("%f", &a[3][1]);
}
```

```c
void display (void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(&a[0][0]);

    // [...]
}
```